# How do I convert MultipartEntityBuilder to inputStream when exception message goes to the deadLetterChannel in camel?

Tags: java, apache-camel

I am sending a file to the server using **MultipartEntityBuilder** When the server not respond or any other exception occurs the file should go to the deadLetterChennal endpoint and save as a file.Everything working fine but deadLetterChennal showing conversion issue.

```
from("direct:sendFileExchange")
 .errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("file:/home/r2/Desktop/ofBizFile/errorFinalServer")
            .asyncDelayedRedelivery()
            .maximumRedeliveries(3)
            .redeliveryDelay(1000)
            .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN))

            .startupOrder(3)
            .process(new ProcessorSetFileRequest())
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY,constant("USERNAME=__&PASSWORD=_"))
            .to("https4://someAddress/uploadAndImportFileFromCSVFile?throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
            .to("stream:out");
```

The deadLetter file not coming in directory.
Where I can set the type converter in my route ?

Error I am getting:

```
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot store file: /home/r2/Desktop/ofBizFile/errorFinalServer/orders-02-01-2018.csv
Caused by: [org.apache.camel.NoTypeConversionAvailableException - No type converter available to convert from type:
org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity to the required type: java.io.InputStream with value org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartFormEntity@ddf0916]
```

Comment: For me useOriginalMessage() is working grt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
 from("direct:sendFileExchange")
            .errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("direct:savefile").useOriginalMessage()
                .asyncDelayedRedelivery()
                .maximumRedeliveries(3)
                .redeliveryDelay(1000)
                .retryAttemptedLogLevel(LoggingLevel.WARN))

            .startupOrder(3)
            .process(new ProcessorSetFileRequest())
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("POST"))
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_QUERY,constant("USERNAME=__&PASSWORD=_"))
            .to("https4://someAddress/uploadAndImportFileFromCSVFile?throwExceptionOnFailure=false")
            .to("stream:out");

 from("direct:savefile").process(exchange -> {
          MultipartFormEntity body = (MultipartFormEntity) exchange.getIn().getBody();
          exchange.getOut().setBody(body.getContent());
        }).to("file:/home/r2/Desktop/ofBizFile/errorFinalServer");
```

Answer (score 0):

import MultipartFormEntity from org.apache.hc.client5.http.entity.mime